Bash regex validation not working properly
I'm doing a CI/CD script for my project, and I'm trying to check if the git tag matches a SemVer regex expression, but this always returns "Not Match".
I try this expression on regex101 site and give "1.0.3" as a test string, it works fine.
#!/bin/bash

SEMVER_FORMAT="^(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)(?:-((?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(?:\.(?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*))?(?:\+([0-9a-zA-Z-]+(?:\.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*))?$"
GIT_TAG="1.0.3"

# Debug: Check the value of GIT_TAG
echo "GIT_TAG: '$GIT_TAG'"

# Test Regex matching
if [[ "$GIT_TAG" =~ $SEMVER_FORMAT ]]; then
    echo "Match"
else
    echo "No Match"
fi

What is wrong with this?

\d is not accepted by bash regex.

Bash uses posix extended regular expressions. That has several non ERE constructs.
